# Instantiate generic Type T on base component Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, extends

I have an super component who is extended by some child component :

```
 export class BaseComponent<T extends InternalItem> {

    private _internalGradientItems: T[];

    constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    }

    protected addRow(item: Item) {
        // here I whant to instatiate the type T. 

    }
}
```

For some reason I need to instantiate the T element on the base component. 
I didn't find any solution to do that. 
The only think which work is to cast object to T.

```
 let iItem = <T>{ gradientItem: item }
```

But I don't like this solution, not clean and safe solution.

Do you have any purpose for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `T` is a class and you want to instantiate it, you need to pass in the constructor to the class to the `BaseComponent`. You can either require an empty constructor, or a constructor that takes in the properties you pass in from `BaseComponent`.

```
export class BaseComponent<T extends InternalItem> {

    private _internalGradientItems: T[];

    constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,public ctor: new (arg: { gradientItem: Item })=> T) {

    }

    protected addRow(item: Item) {
        new this.ctor({ gradientItem: item });
    }
}

//Usage:

class InternalItem { /* base props */ }
class DerivedInternalItem extends InternalItem { 
    /* props */
    constructor(arg:  { gradientItem: Item }) {
        super()
    }
}

export class DerivedComponent extends BaseComponent<DerivedInternalItem> {
    constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        super(cdr, DerivedInternalItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but I m not sure to understand what exactly do this line "ctor: new (arg: { gradientItem: Item })=> T"

Comment: @Yvan  It's a constructor signature. `ctor` will be a constructor function (aka a function you call with `new`) that takes in an `arg` with the specified type and returns a new instance of `T` whatever `T` is